# Mathematica: FindRoot errors

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, equation-solving

```
FindRoot[
 27215. - 7.27596*10^-12 x + 52300. x^2 - 9977.4 Log[1. - 1. x] == 0
 , 
 {x, 0.000001}
]
```

converges to the solution `{x -> -0.0918521}` but how can I get Mathematica to avoid the following error message before the solution:

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Indeterminate} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>
```

I am using FindRoot to solve some pretty messy expressions. I also sometimes receive the following error, though Mathematica will still yield an answer, but am wondering if there is a way to avoid it as well:

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>
```

Comment: Have you tried a different starting point?

Comment: That isn't actually a solution, is it? Looks like there isn't a (real) solution to that equation. (Not sure why Mathematica gives you one.)

Comment: agree with @Jefromi you are getting a number but it is not a solution. There doesn't seem to be a real solution. You could use evaluation monitor and track what is happening and I think you will probably find wild oscillations up until it spits out this number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution you are getting is not the actual solution. The message indicates something was wrong and `FindRoot` returns the last value of `x`. This is the last item under 'More Information' for `FindRoot`:

- If FindRoot does not succeed in finding a solution to the accuracy you specify within `MaxIterations` steps, it returns the most recent approximation to a solution that it found. You can then apply FindRoot again, with this approximation as a starting point.

For example, in this case there is also no solution:

```
FindRoot[x^2 + 1 == 0, {x, 1}]
```

You will get a `FindRoot::jsing` warning and *Mathematica* returns `{x -> 0.}` (which is the most recent approximation).

A similar case like this, but with a `Log` function:

```
FindRoot[1 + Log[1 + x]^2 == 0, {x, 2}]
```

Gives a `FindRoot::nlnum` similar to what you are seeing and returns `{x -> 0.000269448}` (which is the most recent approximation in this case).

This is a plot of the same function, for illustration purposes:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to include complex roots, consider this part of the documentation for `FindRoot` (under 'More Information' also):

- You can always tell FindRoot to search for complex roots by adding 0.I to the starting value.

So, for example, you can take a starting value near one complex root, like so:

```
FindRoot[x^2 + 1 == 0, {x, 1 + 1. I}]
```

Which converges (without messages) to `{x -> 8.46358*10^-23 + 1. I}` (so basically `I`).

Or with a starting value near the other complex root:

```
FindRoot[x^2 + 1 == 0, {x, 1 - 1. I}]
```

You will get basically `-I` (to be precise you get `{x -> 8.46358*10^-23 - 1. I}`).

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a real solution to this equation. Mathematica ends up getting somewhere near the minimum of the function, and reports this because that's where the algorithm converges to.

```
Plot[27215. - 7.27596*10^-12 x + 52300. x^2 - 9977.4 Log[1. - 1. x],
 {x, -2, 0.09}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Mathematica does warn you about this:

```
In[30]:= x /. 
 Table[FindRoot[
   27215. - 7.27596*10^-12 x + 52300. x^2 - 9977.4 Log[1. - 1. x] == 
    0, {x, y}], {y, -0.01, 0.01, 0.0002}]



During evaluation of In[30]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Indeterminate} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Indeterminate} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {Indeterminate} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::nlnum will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances. >>

During evaluation of In[30]:= General::stop: Further output of FindRoot::lstol will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

Out[30]= {-0.0883278, -0.0913649, -0.0901617, -0.0877546, -0.0877383, \
-0.088508, -0.0937041, -0.0881606, -0.0912122, -0.0899562, \
-0.0876965, -0.0879619, -0.0877441, -0.101551, -0.0915088, \
-0.0880611, -0.0959972, -0.0930364, -0.0902243, -0.0877198, \
-0.0881157, -0.107205, -0.103746, -0.100439, -0.0972646, -0.094208, \
-0.0912554, -0.0878633, -0.089473, -0.0884659, -0.0876997, \
-0.0876936, -0.0879112, -0.104396, -0.100987, -0.0976638, -0.0879892, \
-0.087777, -0.0881334, -0.0880071, -0.0880255, -0.0880285, \
-0.0880345, -0.0911966, -0.0879797, -0.0890295, -0.087701, \
-0.0952537, -0.0941312, -0.0929994, -0.0918578, -0.0885677, \
-0.0895444, -0.0883719, -0.103914, -0.102701, -0.0885007, -0.0915083, \
-0.098988, -0.0963068, -0.0891533, -0.0907357, -0.0881215, \
-0.0893928, -0.108191, -0.104756, -0.101456, -0.0982737, -0.0951949, \
-0.0922072, -0.0892996, -0.0878794, -0.0877164, -0.0896659, \
-0.0886859, -0.0876952, -0.0909219, -0.0899049, -0.0888758, \
-0.0878343, -0.0952044, -0.0941281, -0.0887345, -0.0919322, \
-0.0886726, -0.0876955, -0.0877232, -0.0878879, -0.0877578, \
-0.101642, -0.0916633, -0.0991254, -0.0877255, -0.0936139, \
-0.0907846, -0.0877205, -0.0877454, -0.0881589, -0.0893507, \
-0.0878747, -0.0876961}
```

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't even print a warning! (The one the OP's concerned about could presumably be avoided by specifying a range to search in, excluding the bit where the log blows up.) I guess whenever you use FindRoot you have to manually check to see if what it gave you was actually a solution?

Comment: Actually it does print warnings - I just didn't copy them over, sorry.